# javascript function arguments to object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, underscore.js, ecmascript-6

here is using function to insert object to mongo

```
function addTransaction(userId,paymentMethod,product={},status){
  Transactions.insert({
    userId:userId,
    paymentMethod:paymentMethod,
    product:product,
    status:status
  });
}
```

is there any better way to generate the object from arguments or pass the whole object arguments. If so, how to make an object more efficient than like this

```
var dataObj = {
  userId:userId,
  paymentMethod:paymentMethod,
  product:product,
  status:status
}
```

may be can I create an object by var name as key and value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **short object notation**:

```
Transactions.insert({
  userId, // equivalent to userId: userId
  paymentMethod,
  product,
  status
});
```